# Flat Array with full parents (PHP, Symfony 3)

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, multidimensional-array

For a social media login with Xing, I want to verificate the data send from XING as described in https://dev.xing.com/plugins/login_with/docs#signature-verification

My page sends data as JSON-Array to a PHP function

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
       dump($request->request);
       $xingData=\GuzzleHttp\json_decode($request->request->get('xingData'),true);
       $xingUser=$xingData['user'];
       $xingError=$xingData['error'];
       $xingCookie=$request->request->get('xingCookie');
       $xingSerialised= $this->flatArray($xingUser);
       dump($xingUser);
       dump($xingError);
       dump($xingCookie);
       dump($xingSerialised);
       //$xingUserhash=hash_hmac('sha256',$xingSerialised,$this->container->getParameter('xing_salt'));
       //dump($xingUserhash);
        die(0);
        return $this->render('base.html.twig', array(
        ));
    }

function flatArray($fullArray = array())
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($fullArray));
    $elements = array();

    foreach($iterator as $element) {
        $elements[] = $iterator->key().$element;
    }

    return $elements;
}
```

The JSON-decode-Function makes this array:

```
XingController.php on line 36:
array:9 [▼
  "id" => "MyId"
  "first_name" => "MyName"
  "last_name" => "MyLastName"
  "display_name" => "MyDisplayName"
  "active_email" => "my@email.de"
  "permalink" => "https://www.xing.com/profile/MyName"
  "business_address" => array:4 [▼
    "street" => "MyStreet"
    "city" => "MyCity"
    "province" => "MyProvince"
    "country" => "DE"
  ]
  "photo_urls" => array:1 [▼
    "maxi_thumb" => "https://www.xing.com/image/image.jpg"
  ]
  "professional_experience" => array:1 [▼
    "primary_company" => array:3 [▼
      "name" => "MyCompanyName"
      "title" => "Inhaber"
      "industry" => "CONSUMER_SERVICES"
    ]
  ]
]
```

The problem is, I get

```
XingController.php on line 39:
array:14 [▼
  0 => "idMyId"
  1 => "first_nameMyName"
  2 => "last_nameMyLastName"
  3 => "display_nameMyDisplayName"
  4 => "active_emailmy@email.de"
  5 => "permalinkhttps://www.xing.com/profile/MyName"
  6 => "streetMyStreet"
  7 => "cityMyCity"
  8 => "provinceMyProvince"
  9 => "countryDE"
  10 => "maxi_thumbhttps://www.xing.com/image/image.jpg"
  11 => "nameMyCompanyName"
  12 => "titleInhaber"
  13 => "industryCONSUMER_SERVICES"
]
```

But I wanted the full parents with it, for example:

```
 6 => "business_addressstreetMyStreet"
```

Thanks for any idea/help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
function flatArray($fullArray = array())
{
    $elements = array();

    foreach($fullArray as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $elements[] = $this->flatArray($value); 
        } else {
            $elements[] = sprintf('%s%s', $key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $elements;
}
```

Probably the recursion could be improved

Hope this help

Version with full recursion:

```
function flatArray($fullArray = array(), $parentkey=null)
    {
        $elements = array();

        foreach($fullArray as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $elements = array_merge($elements, $this->flatArray($value, $parentkey.$key));
            } else {
                $elements[] = sprintf('%s%s%s', $parentkey, $key, $value);
            }
        }

        return $elements;
    }
```